# In ER diagrams, do relationships between different tables have to be unique?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relationship, entity-relationship

I've been trying to create a database following an ER diagram. In my case I have a table 'admin' where it has a relationship with 4 different tables. I've named the relationships for each one of them 'manages'. So the relationship between them would be

```
'admin' -> manages -> table A 
'admin' -> manages -> table B, etc
```

Is it correct?

I've read different opinions on the internet... Some say yes, some say no. I've asked a teacher of mine and he said each relationship in an ER diagram has to be unique so now I'm confused. Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: This is too vague. And there are many design methods, some ER & some calling themselves ER that aren't., and some use "relationship" as in ER for an association on entities/values while others use it to mean foreign key. But anyway how to map an ER design to DB tables is part of a method. So give your design & name & source your method & explain re how you are stuck following it. PS Such basics are faqs. Always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 0):

When modeling, it doesn't have to be unique but, when implementing at the physical level (the database), it must be unique.

At the physical level, these relationships translates into `foreign key` so, your `Admin manages TableA` will be named something like `FK_Admin_Manages_TableA`, your `Admin manages TableB` will be named `FK_Admin_Manages_TableB` and so on.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I have one more question. Can I set a relatinship between two tables depending on a boolean in one of them?

Comment: If you want a boolean relationship, you have to use subtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Think of relations in an ER schema as 3 choices:

- 1:1 -- possible, but usually bad schema design
- 1:many -- implemented with key of the "1" table in the "many" table
- many:many -- requires an extra 'mapping' table between the two other tables

("0:..." is a degenerate cases of the above)

If only one person can admin something, then it is 1:many; if many can manage many, then many:many.

Comment: Thanks. Many can manage many but only one admin can manage one at the same time and viceversa... would it be many:many too in this case or 1:many? Also, can I set a relationship between two tables based on a boolean? Let's say I have table user and it can be admin or normal user, if it is user.admin = true then it can manage the other tables otherwise not

Comment: If TableA can be managed by only one admin, then that is many:1.  No boolean.  Rethink the idea that there are two types of "person".